# Javascript rating bar don't work with modrewrite urls

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my script, this function parts build links:

```
if ($type == "mod_rewrite") {
    $prepend = "";
    $append = ".html";

} else if ($type == "query_string") {
        $prepend = 'index.php?params=';
        $append = "/";
}
//
//
//
    $gamelink = 'game/id/gamename' (example)
    /* 'game' is a fixed string.  
        'id' and 'gamename' are variables) */
```

and my .htacess is as below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?params=$1 [NC,L]
```

The Problem:

I have in game page a ajax rating bar which works perfectly in query string mode:

(in this examples: gamename = 'Arm Copter' and gameid = '3')

Game link:

```
http://localhost/gss/index.php?params=game/3/Arm-Copter/
```

Rating link (mouse-over stars images)

```
http://localhost/gss/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php?j=10&q=arm_copter&t=127.0.0.1&c=10
```

Using ModRewrite: 
Game Link:

```
http://localhost/gss/game/3/Arm-Copter.html
```

Rating Link (stars missing, show only numbers correspondent to stars):

```
http://localhost/gss/game/3/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php?j=10&q=arm_copter&t=127.0.0.1&c=10
```

The problem here, seems to be url part 'game/id/' inserted, because the correct path to db.php is:

```
http://localhost/gss/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php
```

and not:

```
http://localhost/gss/**game/3/**plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php
```

I spent 2 days searching and testing various approaches, but i don't found a solution. I need a rule which don't rewrite the ajax rating bar or rewrite to correct paths.

Regards,

Junior Senior - Brazil.

Comment: What URIs do you use for reference? You’re probably using the “wrong” ones (probably relative ones).

Comment: Hi Gumbo, 

// The local path of Script on my local server: 
$cfg['instdir'] = 'D:/Program Files/wamp/www/gss/';

The URL of my Script: 
$cfg['baseurl'] = 'http://localhost/gss/';

Path to ajax star rater: 
D:/Program Files/wamp/www/gss/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php

In my index.php, i have this links for the ajax star rater:  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/ajax_star_rater/css/rating.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="plugins/ajax_star_rater/js/rating.js"></script>

What i need to change? To use absolute paths?

Thanks, 

Junior.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution: You have to edit the rating.js -

```
function sndReq(vote,id_num,ip_num,units) {
var theUL = document.getElementById('unit_ul'+id_num); // the UL

// switch UL with a loading div
theUL.innerHTML = '<div class="loading"></div>';

xmlhttp.open('get', 'rpc.php?j='+vote+'&q='+id_num+'&t='+ip_num+'&c='+units);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
```

You need to change this line:

```
xmlhttp.open('get', '../../rpc.php?j='+vote+'&q='+id_num+'&t='+ip_num+'&c='+units);
```

The part before rpc.php need to be `../../`

Answer (score 0):

In the html for the rating link that calls the plugin (http://localhost/gss/game/3/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php) you are probably using a relative path from the current folder, sounds like you need to use a path relative to the root folder.

Instead of:

```
<a href="plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php">Rate me!</a>
```

You need to add a start the link with / and write the full path to the script:

```
<a href="/gss/plugins/ajax_star_rater/db.php">Rate me!</a>
```

Hope that helps.